# spring security principal null/user not logged in on permitAll path

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have spring-security securing some paths in my app and leaving others open for anonymous access. The problem I am running into is related to the open parts where I have left the access as "permitAll". I only want to protect certain paths from access by a non-ADMIN but I do want the admin user to be recognizable when they are in the open parts of the path.

Thymeleaf template (partial):

```
<p>Hello Spring Boot User <span th:text="${username}"/>!</p>
<div sec:authorize="isAnonymous()">isAnonymous</div>
<div sec:authorize="isRememberMe()">isRememberMe</div>
<div sec:authorize="isAuthenticated()">isAuthenticated</div>
<div sec:authorize="isFullyAuthenticated()">isFullyAuthenticated</div>
```

**NOTE:** The model defines the username as:

```
String username = (principal != null ? principal.getName() : "ANONYMOUS");
```

Config (Java based) - there are multiple types of authentication being used

```
@Configuration
public static class FormLoginConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/form/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().formLogin().permitAll().loginPage("/form/login").loginProcessingUrl("/form/login")
                .and().logout().logoutUrl("/form/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
    }
}

@Order(45) // LOW
@Configuration
public static class BasicAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/basic/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
    }
}
```

There is no security config for the /open path. Just a controller. There is also a controller for the /form path. Those are both something like this (just the path varies for now):

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/open")
public class OpenController extends BaseController {
    @RequestMapping({"", "/"})
    public String home(HttpServletRequest req, Principal principal, Model model) {
        commonModelPopulate(req, principal, model);
        return "home"; // name of the template
    }
}
```

If I go to this path **/open** (not protected) I see:

```
Hello Spring Boot User ANONYMOUS!
```

But if I go to this path **/form** (form login protected - after login) I see:

```
Hello Spring Boot User admin! 
isAuthenticated 
isFullyAuthenticated
```

So I think there might be multiple issues here. The first is that the thymeleaf sec:authorize attributes are not doing anything and the second is that it seems like I can only access the Principal and other security info if I am under a protected path.

Is there a way to protect just one path (and sub paths) but allow the Principal and security data to be accessed everywhere else in my app?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your '/open' resource is not mapped to any Security filters. It looks to me like you need a default `WebSecurityConfigurer` (with the default path pattern "/**") and marked as `permitAll()`. It should have a higher `@Order` than the others so it acts as a fallback.

```
@Order(67) // LOWEST
@Configuration
public static class NoAuthConfigurationAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
    }
}
```

Comment: I happened upon this solution through some trial and error but it's great to have this validation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To have access to the spring security infrastructure, you need to configure the spring security filter on all your paths (/*). You do not need a permit-all http configuration. You can add the filter in web.xml ( http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/security-filter-chain.html ) or programmatically ( http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.4.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/context/AbstractSecurityWebApplicationInitializer.html ).

Comment: "You can add the filter in web.xml or programmatically." But... how?